# Github account does not show in google search

Tags: git, github

I cannot find my projects when searching after it (Google, Bing) even if I add github or even if I use my username on the site or even directly on GitHub. What setting should I change?

My repository is about 2 years old. I have about 10 projects of my own and others that have been fork

Answer (score 1):

it your github account is newly created or if it has a less number of repos.... it may take time to show up on google search